# Extraer parte de un string que cumpla expresión regular (RegEx)

Tags: php, regex

Necesito **extraer un substring de una cadena que cumpla una serie de condiciones**. Casi lo he conseguido, pero tengo fallo en la expresión regular y no termino de obtener el resultado buscado.

Recibo un string, con un nombre largo de una tarifa, junto con una letra y número de versión. Por ejemplo: "NOMBRE TARIFA V1 12M". Necesito quedarme solo con la parte "V1".

Siempre seguirá el patrón:
- Una letra (en principio mayúscula, aunque me gustaría aceptar ambas), en mi caso siempre serán las letras: V, L, M.
- Seguido siempre de un número que comienza en 0 y puede llegar hasta 2 cifras. Aquí tengo mi problema, cuando es una cifra, extrae el substring correctamente, cuando son 2 cifras falla y no lo extrae, no encuentra coincidencia.

Os dejo lo que tengo hasta el momento con unos ejemplos incluidos:

```
$var1 = "TARIFA 1.1 NOMBRE TARIFA V1 12M";
$var2 = "TARIFA LDVB8 NOMBRE V5 10M";
$var3 = "TARIFA HD76 V10 12M";
$var4 = "TARIFA NOMBRE4 L3 18M";
$var5 = "TARIFA NOMBRE5 L10 12M";
$var6 = "NO HAY COINCIDENCIA";
$var7 = "TARIFA NOMBRE7 M6 12M";

function extractV($str) {
    if (preg_match('/ [V|L|M][0-9]? /',$str,$coincidencias,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        //Hay coincidencia
        $valorBuscado = $coincidencias[0];
        $version = $valorBuscado[0];
    } 
    else 
    {
        $version = "NO";
    }
    return $version;
}

$extraccion1 = extractV($var1);
echo "<br>Coincidencias1 = ". $extraccion1;

$extraccion2 = extractV($var2);
echo "<br>Coincidencias2 = ". $extraccion2;

$extraccion3 = extractV($var3);
echo "<br>Coincidencias3 = ". $extraccion3;

$extraccion4 = extractV($var4);
echo "<br>Coincidencias4 = ". $extraccion4;

$extraccion5 = extractV($var5);
echo "<br>Coincidencias5 = ". $extraccion5;

$extraccion6 = extractV($var6);
echo "<br>Coincidencias6 = ". $extraccion6;

$extraccion7 = extractV($var7);
echo "<br>Coincidencias7 = ". $extraccion7;
```

Como veis, en las `$var3` y `$var5`, no extrae valor (por ser de 2 cifras el nº que sigue a la letra), pero si debería. ¿Cómo puedo corregir la RegEx? ¿O alguna solución para la extracción de substring con esas características? Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le estás pidiendo sólo un caracter numérico seguido de un espacio, lo cual no se cumple si hay dos.

Debiera ser, en cambio

```
preg_match('/ ([V|L|M][0-9]{1,2})? /',$str,$coincidencias,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

para aceptar ya sea una o dos cifras. También lo envolví en paréntesis para que el segundo elemento del array sea el grupo capturado sin los espacios.

Comment: Perfecto! Justo ahí estaba mi fallo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!